# ImageMagick devel package on Red Hat Open Shift

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paas, openshift

I need ImageMagick with my RoR app, because I use rmagick and carrierwave gems for editing images. How can I install it on Open Shift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

If you access to the ssh you can see the machine comes already with ImageMagick:

```
[blog-fdiazgarrido.rhcloud.com ~]\> convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.5.4-7 2010-02-26 Q16 OpenMP http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2009 ImageMagick Studio LLC
```

So the only thing you have to do is include it in your Gemfile, and it will be picked up like all the other gems

---

---

You have to use first the library with:

```
up2date install ImageMagick
```

or

```
yum install ImageMagick
```

if you are using yum

And finally install the gem like

```
sudo gem install rmagick
```

Or including it on your Gemfile and running bundle

Comment: Thank you, but how can I install it on OpenShift (cloud paas). "yum" is uknown command when I connect with ssh to server. Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok if you access through ssh you can see that ImageMagick is installed, so you only have to include rmagick in your Gemfile, no need to install ImageMagick. editing my answer

Comment: I have in my Gemfile "rmagick", "carrierwave". After push I have this error:

Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find Magick-config in /usr/libexec/stickshift/cartridges/ruby-1.8/info/bin/:/usr/libexec/stickshift/cartridges/abstract-httpd/info/bin/:/usr/libexec/stickshift/cartridges/abstract/info/bin/:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin

Comment: Could you try with this? gem "rmagick", :require => 'RMagick'

Comment: I cant creat any files with ssh connect, it's ok?
It's same problem with :require => 'RMagick'

Comment: Well the problem is that rmagick not only requires Imagemagick installed but also the headers, this headers are not installed. To install them you have to install the package ImageMagick-devel and I dont think this is possible in OpenShift

Comment: Thank you. Maybe Red Hat help me.....
https://openshift.redhat.com/community/kb/kb-e1017-adding-dependencies-to-applications

Comment: Yeap I think thats your best shoot, you might wanna change the comment though, ImageMagick is installed, what you need is the devel package, needed to install he rmagick gem. Also you might wanna put it in the forum: https://openshift.redhat.com/community/forums/openshift